# How to locate PostGIS AMIs on Amazon EC2?

Tags: postgis, amazon-ec2

There are nearly 7000 AMIs on EC2, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out which ones have what I'm looking for--in this case PostGIS on Linux.  No specific version/configuation--I want to check out various ones.

If I enter `postgis` on the AMI search, I get 6 AMIs:

[image]

I know the opengeo AMIs have postgis, but they don't appear.  It appears you have to already know which AMI you are looking for or know which keywords to use.  In this case, `opengeo` will get the results.  But I wouldn't have known that without prior knowledge (opengeo blog post about their AMIs).

Even once I locate an AMI, I'm having a hard time figuring out what it actually is and what software versions without actually starting an instance. The AWS console tells you platform, but not much else unless the creator put it in the description.

There could actually be more `PostGIS` AMIs that aren't discoverable.  Is there an internet source that tracks PostGIS AMIs?  Maybe provides a little more metadata about them?

What are others doing?  Just starting with the OS and installing from package or source themselves (right now, I think that's the easier option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just using the [stock Ubuntu AMIs](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/release/) that are well described and trustworthy and installing the rest using apt.  Its important that the AMI is properly documented (which ubuntu is), otherwise its simpler to just do the setup yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenGeo Suite Community](http://blog.opengeo.org/2010/09/13/opengeo-suite-community-edition-on-amazon-web-services/)

Are you trying to use the same ami as the opengeo?
4.Copy and paste the OpenGeo Suite image AMI ID into the text box and hit enter.
Windows AMI: ami-ea1cf683
Linux AMI: ami-041cf66d

Comment: The question is how to locate AMIs that use postGIS.  Copying and pasting the AMI assumes that you already know that AMI has PostGIS.  How do you initially discover the AMIs to begin with? By the way, that's not the only linux opengeo AMI!