# Any pgrouting enabled hosting providers?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, ubuntu, linux, service-recommendations

I am really interested if any of you know about a hosting provider that offers postgis & pgrouting pre-installed?

If not, can I just go ahead and purchase a linode hosting account and do all the installations myself?

The situation is that I am seeking for a hosting account to launch my pgrouting based application.

Please consider that I am a WIN 7 user with no linux and ubuntu experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mapserverpro.com/

has a number of Web Mapping Applications and Spatial Database hosting capabilities

```
Premium Tier 1 Multi-homed Bandwidth
GIS Software Installer
Plesk Panel with AppVault
Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3, PERL, CGI
Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Passenger
mod_rails, Mongrel, Rack
Python / WSGI
Python Virtual Environment Support
MySQL 5.1, PostgreSQL 8.4, SQLite 2&3
PostGIS 1.4, pgRouting
SSH, SCP, FTP, SFTP, CRON
Ant / Maven 1&2
PROJ 4 / GDAL
Full Subversion and Git support
Secure POP3/IMAP, Webmail
AWStats, Webalizer, Analog Web Stats
```

It is an older version than what is possible with PostGIS 2.0

Try the demos page

http://www.mapserverpro.com/demo.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you will search in vain for something preconfigured with postGIS and pgRouting, but there seems to be [several sites](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGISHosters) hosting PostGIS

You could also try an Amazon EC2 instance, it seems there are [PostGIS AMIs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/how-to-locate-postgis-amis-on-amazon-ec2) available.

When it comes to pgrouting it seems that you'll have to install it yourself, with a good tutorial (possibly combined with an image with PostGIS installed) i guess it should be doable, even with limited linux expirience

Answer (score 1):

[acugis](http://www.acugis.com/postgis-hosting.htm) has postgis w/pgrouting.

You install pgrouting by clicking a button in the control panel (so even a WIN 7 user can do it ;-) )

There may be others, but I don't know...

Answer (score -1):

There are sites where you can host and configure your site. For instance I am using serversAndDomains.com Cloud VPS.

I have configured a site that will allow clients to host their own data, it has a routing algorithm that I developed over the years. It can import OSM or other data (Shapefiles for instance).

The site is running with OSM data (inc routing) for Portugal as a test case but I can import any other country.

Right now, I can share the routing to you as a remote service and import OSM data for your location. 
The Hosting of client data (completly managed by a client like you) is under development and will allow users to remotely import and create customized maps website on this platform. This is possible because I create metadata from imported data and so new map layers can be added quite fast and queried by the system.